# Criar tabela de lixeira

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho as tabelas do banco para guardar os dados, porém quero adicionar uma para guardar os dados de linhas excluídas das outras tabelas, pensei em quatro formas de fazer isso:

1. Criar uma tabela `lixeira` que guardará o nome da tabela e a chave primária da linha deletada (além de outras informações como data, usuário que deletou, etc.), nas outras tabelas adicionaria um campo `deletado` do tipo booleano, assim, ao invés de excluir a linha apenas altera esse valor (além de cadastrar uma linha na tabela `lixeira`)
2. Criar uma tabela `lixeira` que guardará apenas as informações como data, usuário que deletou, etc., nas outras tabelas adicionaria um campo `deletado` que seria um chave estrangeira para a tabela `lixeira`, assim, ao invés de excluir a linha apenas altera esse valor (além de cadastrar uma linha na tabela `lixeira`)
3. Criar uma tabela `lixeira` que guardará as informações como data, usuário que deletou, etc. e os dados da linha deletada formatados como JSON, excluindo a linha da tabela original
4. Criar uma tabela lixeira para cada tabela do banco, por exemplo, `usuario_lixeira`, `produto_lixeira`, etc., e, antes de excluir os dados na tabela original, adiciona-los na sua tabela lixeira

Em geral, qual seria a melhor alternativa? Que problemas eu terei em usar o método A ou B? Se precisar eventualmente pesquisar uma linha excluída, algum método pode tornar isso muito complicado? Manter os dados excluídos na tabela original (método 1 e 2) reduzirá a performance de consultas ***** ? A indexação pode resolver esse último problema?

***** Considerando uma tabela que possui muitos registros e que são excluídos com relativa frequência

Outras formas de obter o mesmo objetivo são bem vindas,

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2):

O que é melhor só você sabe porque só você está fazendo o caso concreto. Eu não sei se é porque as pessoas não entendem isso, ou se elas são teimosas mesmo, ou se acham que eu e outras pessoas, como o Bacco por exemplo, só falamos besteira. Porque o tempo todo a gente fala dessas coisas coisas e todo mundo acha que existe resposta mágica que atende todo caso. Não existe. Precisa muito mais informação para tomar a decisão. E a descrição atual tem momento que dá a impressão de ser sobre uma tabela, em outra sobre poucas ou muitas, ou todas, o que muda a decisão.

E não tem informação porque precisa destas tabelas, então não sei se 4 é útil ou a 3 é melhor. Na verdade não sei se eu usaria JSON. E poderia usar outra forma, o fato é que a 3 e 4 deleta o original e isso me parece mais importante decisão. Tem cara que seja uma dessas duas, mas tenho até medo de falar isso, porque pode estar faltando informação. Não sei se faz sentido manter o original ou não.

Se precisa manter o dado na tabela por alguma razão, e pode ter razão, há quem diga que nada deveria ser efetivamente deletado (o que não deixa de ser apenas uma receita de bolo, por isso sou contra se falado assim), então me parece que a melhor opção é:

5. Deixa tudo na tabela original e controla a auditoria nela mesmo tendo colunas opcionais e índices adequados considerado as linhas deletadas. Não tem tabela auxiliar, se isso não criar um problema que eu não sei.

Vejo pouco motivo nos bancos de dados atuais para usar 1 ou 2. Aí quem vai escolher ela precisaria justificar porque precisa fazer isso, eu não vejo motivo. Economizar espaço? Gastará mais (se tudo isso for confirmado). Os detalhes de como fazer isto pode ser tão ou mais importantes. Mas manter muita coisa deletada na mesma tabela pode não ser bom. O índice certamente é importante, mas se fora muita deleção mesmo até o índice pode ser prejudicado, mas é pouco, índice tem uma deterioração logarítmica, então não é um grande problema, o limite físico pode ser pior, e ele importa também.

Tentando inferir pelo escrito eu chutaria que 3 ou 4 seriam melhores dependendo da quantidade de tabelas e da necessidade de acessar esses dados deletados com frequência. Algumas coisas me fazem crer que não precisa manter o dado deletado original, mas isso já pode ser um erro conceitual, então não afirmo 100% se é isso. Eu poderia fazer algo como:

6. Criar uma tabela `lixeira` que guardará `tabela`, `linha`, `coluna` e `valor`, incluindo aí as colunas exclusivas dela que não veem da original.

Ou eu faria o 3, mas em formato mais simples que JSON, mas poderia usar o 3 puro. Ou não faria nada disso porque o problema é outro. Não estou descartando a 4, tem mérito em certos cenários.

E pode ter outros desafios que não estão cobertos aí.

Comment: Por isso o "em geral", ou seja, nos casos mais comuns como um pequeno sistema pra um comércio do tio. A ideia da pergunta mesmo era encontrar possíveis falhas e problemas que encontraria em usar algum deles. Obrigado pelas duas outras formas. Mas qual formato você usaria em vez de JSON? No caso da 6, teria uma linha pra cada coluna de cada linha excluída? E como ficaria os outros dados (quem excluiu, data, etc)?

Comment: Você teria códigos especiais para elas. Ela tem vantagem quando alteração também usa este mecanismo, o que deveria, afinal mecanismo de auditoria que só faz com deletados não me parece que seja razoável. Por isso eu disse que deve ter outras falhas na ideia. O formato depende da necessidade.

Comment: Achei muito boa a resposta, poderia adicionar o comentário em relação a opção 6, que tem vantagem quando usado em alterações também. Uma justificativa do uso da opção 1 ou 2 é que um dado não pode ser deletado, por exemplo, em um sistema de estoque, se o comerciante não quer mais trabalhar com um produto, ele irá exclui-lo, porém isso pode causar erros graves em um futuro relatório. Pode aparecer gastos/ganhos que não batem e até quebrar a aplicação, porém é um sistema simples não precisa guardar todas as alterações feitas, de repente nem precisa da data e usuário que excluiu ...

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não sei se entendi o que você quer...

Comment: ... um booleano pode ser o suficiente, mas também pode ser que tenha mais de um administrador desses produtos e seja útil saber quem excluiu o que. Em casos como a OLX, um usuário pode excluir seus anúncios, mas de repente a empresa precisa retirar relatórios semanais e mensais dos motivos que levaram os usuários a excluírem os anúncios para melhorar a ferramenta, fazer essa busca no caso 3 com o formato JSON ou outro pode ser complicado né? E o fato de ter centenas de anúncios criados e apagados diariamente (provavelmente mais), manter na tabela original poderá ser um problema? ...

Comment: Qual opção usar? Nesse caso, talvez eles queiram manter o histórico de mudanças, e então usariam a opção 6, mas como garantir a integridade dos dados? Não é possível usar uma FK que use 3 colunas para referenciar uma PK, ou tem como?

Comment: A sua reposta é boa, mas como pode ver eu ainda tenho umas lacunas abertas, essa dúvida não pra um sistema específico, mas usaria de base para decidir nos futuros que irei fazer

Comment: Aí você está dando outro contexto, e até seu comentário mostra que não tem um requisito claro, portanto nem eu, nem você podemos responder o quer é melhor. Você pode usar uma FK como quiser. O seu problema é justamente ter lacunas, você ainda não sabe qual é o seu problema, por isso não tem como saber qual é a solução. Primeiro tem que decidir o que precisa, pra depois escolher uma opção.